# problems implementing websocket exercise using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, websocket

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration

@EnableWebSocket

public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{

@Override

public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {

registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/user").setAllowedOrigins("\*").withSockJS();

}

@Bean

public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {

return new MyHandler();

}

}
```

SocketTextHandler.java

```
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

private Set\<WebSocketSession\> sessions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

@Override

public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {

sessions.add(session);

System.out.print("연결");

}

@Override

public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage\<?\> message) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override

public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override

public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override

public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return false;

}

}
```

MyHandler.java

```
public class MyHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

private Set\<WebSocketSession\> sessions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

@Override

public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {

sessions.add(session);

System.out.print("hi");

}

@Override

public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage\<?\> message) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override

public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override

public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override

public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return false;

}

}
```

i configurate code above this.
when i check through postman
ws://localhost:8080/user
it doesn't work...
i already have checked the port is 8080..
Do i have something left?

when i check through postman
ws://localhost:8080/user
it doesn't work...
i already have checked the port is 8080..
Do i have something left?